# gulp build with browser sync and react not reloading page

Tags: node.js, reactjs, gulp, browser-sync

I have a gulpfile with the following `build` task:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    source = require('vinyl-source-stream'),
    buffer = require('vinyl-buffer'),
    babelify = require('babelify'),
    browserify = require('browserify'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
    bs = require('browser-sync').create('BrowserSync');

gulp.task('build', function () {
    return browserify({entries: './src/app.js', debug: true})
        .transform("babelify", { presets: ['es2015','react'] })
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source('app.js'))
        .pipe(buffer())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./maps'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js'))
        .pipe(bs.reload({stream: true}));
});
```

The process builds my files perfectly, however my browser does not load. Why doesn't my browser reload? And how do I achieve the desired behavior? I feel like I am missing something about `BrowserSync`.

**NOTE:** I am fairly confident `BrowserSync` is working properly as I call `bs.reload()` in another task, and the page reloads perfectly. Happy to paste in more code however if needed.

Comment: I created a gulp, react & browser sync startup repo some time ago, here's the link to the gulpfile: https://github.com/rhernandog/react-gulp-startup/blob/master/gulpfile.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gulp task that started browsersync was run by `gulp` as it was triggered in the default task.

Then I ran `gulp build` manually from the terminal, and here was the issue. This manual command thus did not have access to the instance of `browsersync` that was created by the default gulp process.

So having `gulp build` run automatically with the instantiated version available did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a snippet from a [starter project](https://github.com/cmseaton42/react-gulp-sass-boilerplate) that I started a while back that does what you are mentioning...

```
/*...*/
gulp.task('watchify', () => {
  let args = merge(watchify.args, { debug: true })
  let bundler = watchify(browserify('./src/js/app.js', args)).transform(babelify, { presets: ["es2015", "react"] })
  bundle(bundler)

  bundler.on('update', () => {
    bundle(bundler)
  })
})


function bundle(bundler) {
  return bundler.bundle()
    .on('error', map_error)
    .pipe(source('app.js'))
    .pipe(buffer())
    .pipe(rename('app.min.js'))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init({ loadMaps: true }))
      // capture sourcemaps from transforms
      .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./maps'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js'))
    .pipe(sync.reload({
            stream: true
    }))
}
/*...*/

// watching multiple files with a task 'watch'
gulp.task('default', () => {
    gulp.watch('src/js/**/*.js', ['watchify']);
});
```

Comment: Huh looks pretty similar to me. I can't tell what's wrong.

Comment: sorry this is just a task I run via a `gulp.watch` call. See the edit.